# How to build a ReactNative app in release mode for the ios app store?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, command-line-interface

I'm new to ReactNative and I built a little 'hello world' app.

I'm not using expo, I created my app using the React Native CLI Quickstart.

There are very clear instructions on how to build the app for Android & Google play store here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

I was able to follow those directions and I was successful.

How do I do the same for an ios production build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at the following links

[react-native-deployment-to-iphone](https://medium.com/@kswanie21/react-native-deployment-to-iphone-76d8254f1505)

[deploying-react-native-app-ios-android-windows](https://www.ileafsolutions.com/blog/deploying-react-native-app-ios-android-windows/)

[how-to-deploy-a-react-native-ios-app-on-the-app-store](https://readybytes.in/blog/how-to-deploy-a-react-native-ios-app-on-the-app-store)

Comment: Thanks it really helped.